# C/C++ Compiler Missing on NetBeans 7.3 on Debian

Tags: c++, debian, netbeans-7.3

I have installed Debian 7.0.0 and have just installed the full version of NetBeans 7.3 which is supposed to have C/C++ building capabilities.  However, when I start, I get the message

```
No C/C++ Compilers Found
```

I did a search for this error message and Bugzilla said it was obsolete instructions.  However, when I try to build a C++ application, it gives error highlights for standard C++ includes and gives a pop-up asking for the location of the C++ compiler  and Makefile.  I thought these were both provided by IDEs that are supposed to support C++.

All of my C/C++ compilers (or their names at least) are in

```
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions
```

However, when I try to execute them, they behave like they are not there

```
peter@app-server:~$ ls /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/g++
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/g++
peter@app-server:~$ /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/g++
bash: /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/g++: Permission denied
peter@app-server:~$ sudo /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/g++
sudo: /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/g++: command not found
peter@app-server:~$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you actually have a compiler installed. Typing `g++ -v` on the command line is the easiest way to verify that (and you also get to know which version you're using by default).

If you don't have a compiler yet, `aptitude install build-essential` will install the bare minimum.

Comment: I fixed the compiler problem with something along those lines.  I logged in as root and ran "aptitude install g++".  However your solution looks better since it provides other tools.  Thanks very much!